# Как исправить символы, пример, Fotográfico из-за ударения ломается код XML?

Tags: php, xml

В XML файле присутствует текст, пример: Fotogr**á**fico из-за чего ломается структура XML файла, чем почистить строку перед выводом?

Делаю так `echo $category = iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $category);`
 работает, но буквы просто удаляются, хотелось бы их сохранить.

//TRANSLIT работает не корректно

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что используете для генерации файла?

Comment: Я получаю готовый файл в ISO-8859-1 кодировке и далее работаю с ним на PHP.